# How to solidify the order in which Bazel builds objects

Tags: c++, bazel

I'm using Google Bazel to build a program. When I make a large change that affects multiple files, and rebuild, Bazel chooses one file at random to display the error message for. This causes a lot of editor churn, and I constantly lose my context. I fix one compilation error in one file, then rebuild, but I cannot see whether or not the fix worked because Bazel decides to fail on some other file.

Specifically if I have a target

```
cc_binary(name='foo',
          srcs=['bar.cc', 'qux.cc'])
```

and I run `$ bazel build :foo` then I will get error messages for `bar.cc`. If I run again without making any changes, then I will get (maybe) error messages.for `qux.cc`. I don't know what governs the randomness. Perhaps it is not meant to be known by mere mortals such as my lowly self?

Is there a way to solidify the order in which Bazel builds files, so that I don't have to jump "physically" and mentally between files? Reorienting mental context takes time, and when fixing dumb typos, that time is totally wasted.

What I would love is something like `make` whereby you can say `$ make foo.o`. Then I can fix `foo.cc`, and *only after it builds* then move on to `bar.cc`. Does Alphabet Google support such an advanced method?

Comment: I've used the `--jobs` flag to help with this, as @mhlopko also noted below. The docs say `The number of concurrent jobs to run. 0 means build sequentially.` so I suggest a value of 0.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`--keep_going`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--keep_going)

That will tell bazel not to stop at the first error it finds, and instead try to build everything it can.

Comment: Adding on, without `--keep_going`, the build will fail at the first error it encounters. As Bazel is traversing the dependency graph in a concurrent manner, it is extremely difficult to provide a deterministic error trace without exploring the entire graph. That's why `--keep_going` will work here.

Comment: You can also run with --jobs=1 to make the output be less "racy".